# F# generics for inner functions

Tags: f#

I have the below code:

```
type IQuery = 
    abstract List<'T> : unit -> IList<'T>


let create (str)=
   let getList () : IList<'T> = upcast List<'T>()
   { new IQuery with
      member this.List<'T>() = getList<'T>()
```

And for the last line it gives me a warning stating that:

*The method or function 'getList' should not be given explicit type argument(s) because it does not declare its type parameters explicitly*

However if I remove <'T> from getList call then I get a compilation error as :

The member 'List<'T> : unit -> IList<'a>' does not have the correct type to override the corresponding abstract method. The required signature is 'List<'T> : unit -> IList<'T>'.

What can I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare `getList` with an explicit type parameter:

```
let getList<'T> () : IList<'T> = upcast List<'T>()
```

You then get an error:

> Explicit type parameters may only be used on module or member bindings

If you then move the `let` binding to the top-level at the same scope as the `type`, it all works:

```
type IQuery = 
    abstract List<'T> : unit -> IList<'T>

let getList<'T> () : IList<'T> = upcast List<'T>()

let create (str) =
       { new IQuery with
          member this.List<'T>() = getList<'T>()
       }
```

If your real code has `getList` using values only in scope in `create`, like `str`, you'll need to add them as explicit parameters to `getList`.